# Mint 17.2 Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: linux-mint, package-management

I recently installed Mint 17.2 (Rafalea) on a `HP-255 G1` laptop. It was one of the smoothest installs I have ever done. However I have found a major issue with the `Synaptic Package Manager`. Whilst it lets me install new packages I cannot select other options. The most frustrating of these is that, I am unable to upgrade packages that are out of date. Re-install and Remove are also unselectable. Whist I could go to the command line I am reluctant to do so as it has lead me to dependency hell - obviously would be happy to use it to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours Googling I found a post that suggested that the  issue was with *mintinstall* and advised running the following:-

```
apt-get purge mintinstall
apt-get install mintinstall
```

After running these and a reboot the *Synaptic Package Manager* behaved in its normal manner. The puzzling thing was that there was no suggestion that *mintinstall* was either broken or out-of-date.

Comment: The "suggestion" does appear in the `Update Manager`, when there is an update to Update Manager.  If so, it appears as the only available update.  Have a look at `Mint Menu -->  Administration --> Update Manager`  I know this sounds counter intuitive, but never assume Debian Based behaviors will work in Mint.  I.e the Update Manager GUI should be used in lieu of the command line.

Comment: this doesn't work for me! **:-(** - i just can not upgrade packages via synaptic (only by double-clicking the package) and after purging and installing `mintinstall` or also `mintupdate` nothing changed!